# How to convert datetime to datetime never second (TSQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a DATETIME variables, in this mode  `'2017-01-01 08:50:00'`

I want to have this: `'2017-01-01 08:50'` excluding the seconds part .

How can I do this in t-sql?

Comment: Why in TSQL - this is a display issue not a data issue!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
convert(char(16), @date, 20)
```

where `@date` is a variable with your datetime for convert. Or add column instead `@date` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Elegant solution if SQL Server 2012 is used.

```
SELECT FORMAT(DateColumnName, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
```

Comment: `FORMAT` looks cool, but have very poor performance https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but